# navigator.geolocation support in web server

Tags: php, html, geolocation, navigator

this is my first time to give question on stackoverflow , because I can't find the answer..

I recently have 3 host (if ok to mention ) :

1. Hostgat**.com
2. inmotionhost***.com
3. ipag*.com

-- this is the basic code

```
if(navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(pos) {
      if (is_echo){ return; }
      is_echo = true;
      success(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);
    }, 
    function() {
      if (is_echo){ return; }
      is_echo = true;
      fail();
    }
  );
} else {
  fail();
}
```

---

This code has several feedback:

in first and second works. (ok with android galaxy tab with gps enabled )
Why on third does not work. (always fail in android galaxy tab with gps enabled)

**Is navigator require php mod mod_geoip2**

if so , I have search that hostgat**.com does not support it in shared.
why working. I am sorry for messy question, I am all new in geolocation.

Thank you for stackoverflow has provide us with ... excellent samples...

Luckman R

Comment: its ok to share what you have tried, so try removing the asterisks, i can easily understand its hostgator, ipage and so on..

Answer (score 0):

```
if(navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(pos) {
      if (is_echo){ return; }
      is_echo = true;
      success(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);
    }, 
    function() {
      if (is_echo){ return; }
      is_echo = true;
      fail();
    },{
         enableHighAccuracy: true
              ,timeout : 5000
    }
  );
} else {
  fail();
}
```

Hi, 
Geolocation  with android devices have some problem always just try with this code i have added two lines might work..if not reply back..

Comment: Hi There, the problem is .. It's work with other webserver. Only in the third host, it does not work, the first and second web works..

Comment: and by the way, thank you for your help. :). All we want to know is... Is mod_geoip2 is a must to use navigator.geolocation thank you